# Javascript Regexp behaves odd when trying to match non-whitespace with working demo

Tags: javascript, regex

Well, I just don't seem to understand certain things about `RegExp`.
Can someone please shed some light on me? Are there some implicit words in `RegExp` which result in a nonmatch? My assumption is that the substring "slt" contains some hidden top secret James Bond sign which makes the `RegExp` fail.

Demo to fiddle around:
[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ybGv6/5/)

```
//does not work
var funcArgString="c09__id slt ccc";
var myRegExp = new RegExp("([^ \s]*) ([^ \s]*) ([^ \s]*)","g");
alert(myRegExp.exec(funcArgString));

//works... why???
var funcArgString="c09__id abcdefg ccc";
var myRegExp = new RegExp("([^ \s]*) ([^ \s]*) ([^ \s]*)","g");
alert(myRegExp.exec(funcArgString));

//works as well
var funcArgString="c09__id slt ccc";
var myRegExp = new RegExp("(.*) (.*) (.*)","g");
alert(myRegExp.exec(funcArgString));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you you want to use a backslash `\` in you regex, you have to use two `\\` if you pass the expression as **string**:

```
var myRegExp = new RegExp("([^\\s]*) ([^\\s]*) ([^\\s]*)","g");
```

The backslash is the escape character in JavaScript strings and it will be evaluated as such. To insert a literal backslash, you have to escape it (hence the double backslash).

Also note that you can omit the extra space in the character group, as it is already covered by `\s`.

I assume JavaScript is discarding `\s` as invalid  character sequence and takes `s` literally.

This is the resulting expression of you only use **one** backlash:

```
> new RegExp("([^\s]*) ([^\s]*) ([^\s]*)","g");
  /([^s]*) ([^s]*) ([^s]*)/g
```

> My assumption is that the `slt` contains some hidden top secret james bond sign which makes the regexp fail

Yes, the villain is `s` in this case ;) `([^s]*)` matches every character *but* an `s` so the first string is not matched.

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ybGv6/6/)

Alternatively, you can use a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). As it is literal (and not in a string), we don't have to escape the backlash:

```
var funcArgString="c09__id slt ccc";
var myRegExp = /([^\s]*) ([^\s]*) ([^\s]*)/g;
alert(myRegExp.exec(funcArgString));
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, instead of using `[^\s]` you can use `\S`, which is the same thing.

Comment: Good to know, looks more slick :)